# Adding special characters to xml output

Tags: xslt

We have a piece of code which returns XML in a format like:

Source XML:

```
<Root>
    <Book>
        <BookId>a</BookId>
        &lt;Description&gt;aDescription&lt;/Description&gt;
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <BookId>b</BookId>
        &lt;Description&gt;bDescription&lt;/Description&gt;
    </Book>
</Root>
```

I want to replace the special characters with the literal characters...

```
&lt;
```

will be < etc.

I know I can use:

```
<xsl:character-map name="escapeMapper">
    <xsl:output-character character="&lt;" string="&lt;"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&gt;" string="&gt;"/>        
</xsl:character-map>
```

However here is the twist, I want to convert special characters first, then run the resulting XML through other templates.  So, I want to run the source XML through a template replacing the special characters, putting the result in to a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
```

Now I can use the multi-pass technique and apply other templates using the variable as the source.

How can I convert the special characters into the literal characters?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is not convert `&lt;` and `&gt;` to `<` and `>`, but to *parse* the XML, yes?  Are you able to use Saxon extension functions in what you're doing?  If so, I think you could do something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="loaded">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="$loaded/*" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Book/text()[normalize-space()]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="saxon:parse(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Though this assumes that the text children of `Book` would always be well-formed XML in its own right.

Comment: I'm not sure, we are using apache camel to do the XSLT processing, so at this point we are not using any implementation specific XSLT processing.  To your point, I guess you are correct that we don't necessarily need to replace the special chars....but doing so allows us to apply XPATH/XSLT processing easier